# How to change default password in GeoServer

Tags: web-mapping

I started to learn GeoServer to publish online maps.
I installed the software and now I would like to change the default password. At the moment is: geoserver
I tried to do it without result.
Can anyone explain me how to do this?

Comment: did you follow this document? https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/webadmin/passwords.html  If you did what did not work?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Yes, I did it but I have a message of: "denied access".

Comment: you need to be logged in to change the password, you also need to make sure the user running GeoServer can write to the data directory\

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Hello Ian, thanks for explanation and sorry for my error.

Comment: @Massimiliano If I am understanding your comment it seems like your problem is logging in, not changing the password (at least at this stage).  What are you trying to authenticate with is it admin/geoserver?  If that does not work someone changed it or you are using a different installer than the native GeoServer package.

Comment: I will try to explain what I did. I installed Geoserver using this manual: https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/installation/win_binary.html. I did login in the page http://localhost:8080/geoserver with Username: admin and Passw:  geoserver.I can see the user interface. I added the string <loginEnabled>true</loginEnabled>` in the masterpws/../config.xml. I also read this page https://docs.boundlessgeo.com/bse/latest/sysadmin/security/adminpwd.html#:~:text=Boundless%20Server%20Enterprise.-,Changing%20the%20admin%20password,Click%20Change%20it but I cannot change the password. Thanks to all

Comment: In that case, its probably as @IanTurton suggested and you do not have the correct permissions on the /data directory

Comment: Hello, then probably I must to change something in the data/directory..? How can I be sure that I can write the file? Thanks to all!!!!

Comment: Hello guys, I resolved and now I changed the password and I can work.I re-installed geoserver and followed the instruction in the manual, Thanks for your help.